# Why does compiling tools.cli result in vector args error?

Tags: clojure, command-line-interface

I am moving from `[org.clojure/tools.cli "0.1.0"]` to 0.2.2, but am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" clojure.lang.ArityException: 
Wrong number of args (2) passed to: PersistentVector
```

at the line beginning with `(cli args`

```
(defn parse-opts
  "Using the newer cli library, parses command line args."
  [args]
  (cli args
       ["--ifn1" ".csv input file" :default "benetrak_roster.csv"]
       ["--ifn2" ".csv input file" :default "billing_roster.csv"]
       ["--rpt" ".csv pipe delimited output file" :default "bene_gic_rpt.csv"]
       ["--dump1" "text file report for debug output" :default "dumpfile1.txt"]
       ["--dump2" "text file report for debug output" :default "dumpfile2.txt"]
       ["--debug" "Debug flag for logging." :default 0 :parse-fn #(Integer. %)]))
```

tools.cli is included like this (:use clojure.tools.cli).

I can't see what I'm doing wrong, and would appreciate any pointers or help. Thanks.

By the way, I've tried the following from looking at examples, and it does not work:

```
(defn -main 
  [& args]
  (let [[opts args banner]
        (cli args
        ["--ifn1" ".csv input file" :default "benetrak_roster.csv"]
        ["--ifn2" ".csv input file" :default "billing_roster.csv"]
        ["--rpt" ".csv pipe delimited output file" :default "bene_gic_rpt.csv"]
        ["--dump1" "text file report for debug output" :default "dumpfile1.txt"]
        ["--dump2" "text file report for debug output" :default "dumpfile2.txt"]
        ["--debug" "Debug flag for logging." :default 0 :parse-fn #(Integer. %)])
        start-time (str (Date.))]
        .
        .
        .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
(ns test.core
  (:use clojure.tools.cli))

(defn parse-opts
  "Using the newer cli library, parses command line args."
  [args]
  (cli args
       ["--ifn1" ".csv input file" :default "benetrak_roster.csv"]
       ["--ifn2" ".csv input file" :default "billing_roster.csv"]
       ["--rpt" ".csv pipe delimited output file" :default "bene_gic_rpt.csv"]
       ["--dump1" "text file report for debug output" :default "dumpfile1.txt"]
       ["--dump2" "text file report for debug output" :default "dumpfile2.txt"]
       ["--debug" "Debug flag for logging." :default 0 :parse-fn #(Integer. %)]))

test.core> (parse-opts [])
[{:debug 0, :dump2 "dumpfile2.txt", :dump1 "dumpfile1.txt", :rpt "bene_gic_rpt.csv", :ifn2 "billing_roster.csv", :ifn1 "benetrak_roster.csv"} [] "Usage:\n\n Switches  Default              Desc                              \n --------  -------              ----                              \n --ifn1    benetrak_roster.csv  .csv input file                   \n --ifn2    billing_roster.csv   .csv input file                   \n --rpt     bene_gic_rpt.csv     .csv pipe delimited output file   \n --dump1   dumpfile1.txt        text file report for debug output \n --dump2   dumpfile2.txt        text file report for debug output \n --debug   0                    Debug flag for logging.           \n"]
test.core>
```

Are you sure the error isn't in whatever you're passing to `parse-opts`?

Also: are you sure you've got the right version (and ONLY the right version) of tools.cli in your project.clj?

Comment: Wonderful catch. A dependent module was needlessly bringing in the old version of tools.cli. Thanks.